# R: simplify addition of column based on values in previous columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a function to add a new column to a dataframe based on an existing column. My code currently looks like:

```
df <- data.frame("chr" = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chrX"), "B" = c("a", "c", "d", "b"))

df$chr <- factor(df$chr, levels = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chrX")) # Not really necessary here...
```

I'm using the following function to add a new column with integer values for the chromosome numbers. I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this, perhaps utilizing the factor levels. Also replacing the current df$chr column with the integer values would work as well.

```
AddChr <- function(DataFrame){
  DataFrame$Chr <- NA
  DataFrame$Chr[DataFrame$chr == "chr1"] <- 1
  DataFrame$Chr[DataFrame$chr == "chr2"] <- 2
  DataFrame$Chr[DataFrame$chr == "chr3"] <- 3
  DataFrame$Chr[DataFrame$chr == "chrX"] <- 20
  DataFrame$Chr <- as.integer(DataFrame$Chr)
  return(DataFrame)
}

df <- AddChr(df)
```

Comment: I can understand how `"chr3"` becomes `3`, but how does `"chrX"` become `20`?

Comment: @BlueMagister I tried to shorten the whole series it actually goes from "chr1" to "chr19", then "chrX" is 20 and "chrY" is 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example, this will work

```
df$Chr <- ifelse(grepl("\\d", df$chr), gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", df$chr), 20)
df
##    chr B Chr
## 1 chr1 a   1
## 2 chr2 c   2
## 3 chr3 d   3
## 4 chrX b  20
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution creates a named vector that translates your labels to the new labels.

You desire at the end the numbers 1 through 21 as your labels: `1:21`

The names that you want to translate from are the characters `chr` followed by `c(1:19, "X", "Y")`.

```
paste0("chr", c(1:19, "X", "Y"))
#  [1] "chr1"  "chr2"  "chr3"  "chr4"  "chr5"  "chr6"  "chr7"  "chr8"  "chr9"  "chr10"
# [11] "chr11" "chr12" "chr13" "chr14" "chr15" "chr16" "chr17" "chr18" "chr19" "chrX" 
# [21] "chrY
```

If you name the first vector with the second vector, then you get a mapping:

```
setNames(1:21, paste0("chr", c(1:19, "X", "Y")))
#  chr1  chr2  chr3  chr4  chr5  chr6  chr7  chr8  chr9 chr10 chr11 chr12 chr13 chr14 
#     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14 
# chr15 chr16 chr17 chr18 chr19  chrX  chrY 
#    15    16    17    18    19    20    21
```

Then subset by your vector:

```
# setNames(1:21, paste0("chr", c(1:19, "X", "Y")))[df$chr]
# chr1 chr2 chr3 chr4 
#    1    2    3    4
```